# Was the passenger manifest available all the time?

Tags: lost-in-space, lost-in-space-2018

In one the last episodes of [Lost in Space](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5232792/)'s first season, Maureen can be seen browsing what appears like a list with names and portrait photographs of all colonists

> while trying to identify suitable pilots for having a single Jupiter lander rendezvous with the Resolute in orbit

**Has this list been available the entire time, and accessible on all Jupiter ships/to everyone?**

I cannot remember any mention of such a list becoming available/accessible at some point (which sounds like the answer could be "yes"). On the other hand, even when there were slight doubts about

> "Dr. Smith"'s (June Harris's)

trustworthiness, no-one seemed to bother to simply look her up in said list in order to at least confirm her identity.

> In episode 1x06, Don West even makes a point about having had more proof such as photographs of the real Dr. Smith, but having lost it. His regret about losing that evidence seems out of place if there is a passenger manifest that can simply be checked as soon as someone is suspected to be lying about their identity, and which will serve as sufficient proof on its own.

Comment: Downvoter, please make sure to explain in a comment whether there is anything unclear in the question that I might be able to clarify. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most plausible explanation is that the directory's contents are somehow limited to the occupants of the nearby Jupiters.

Note the directory included entrance detailed test scores for each person, a piece of information that would be expected to be limited to a need-to-know basis, and the Robinsons had no need to know that information for anyone else.

Likely the list was voluntarily collected from each of the Jupiters at some point. Dr. Smith and Angela lost their Jupiters and so they had no records in the system.